# How to Create WSDL? integrating one application with another app?

Tags: wsdl

I'm involving in integrating one application to another.. how can i create WSDL and how? From where can i start.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more detail here

Comment: You need to provide details like : which system you want to integrate with, technology, salesforce to third party or opposite ?